# Get commits without review

Tags: jira, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible, eyeql

I have a list of **JIRA** issues that have one or many commits:

- J1 (c11, c12, ..., c1n)
- J2 (c21, c22, ..., c2m)

...

- Jk (ck1, ck2, ..., cky)

where n,m,y >= 1

Using **Crucible** I'm trying to create reviews for J1,..., Jk (or for c11, ..., cky - because it's ok if the number of Crucible reviews is bigger than the number of JIRA issues).

In order to achieve this, I want to see using **EyeQL** which are the **commits without** a created **review** (not necessarily closed).

If I run the following query:

```
select ...
from ...
where
...
and not reviewed 
group by ...
return ...
```

it returns only the commits that don't have a "complete" review. But I want to see only the commits that don't have a "review" (regardless of its state).

How can I achieve this behavior?

I want something like `and doesn't have any created review` instead of `and not reviewed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the clause `not in any review` should work, i.e.:

```
select revisions from dir "/" where (not in any review) order by date  desc  group by changeset return path, revision, author, date, csid
```

See [the EyeQL reference](https://fisheye.dev.internal.atlassian.com/search/FE-git/) for the full grammar description with examples.